Can't change Annotation Text size
How do you change the Annotation Text size on the Database Diagrams screens in SQL Server Management Studio v19.0.1 ?
Yes, you can click on Tools\Options, then select the "Environment\Fonts and Colors" tab... but no matter what I put in here, each new Annotation which I add gets a default font of Segoe UI, with a large font size of 27.

If I look through the various default font sizes in the "Font and Colors" dialog, 27 isn't mentioned anywhere, and if I try changing the font size, nothing changes.  Any new Annotations which I add to my diagrams continue to be in 27pt font.
So, for every Text Annotation that I add to my Database Diagram, I have to manually select a reasonable font size.
Update
I did some more experimenting today.  It seems that, when you change the font family, size & color for "Table and Database Designers", it doesn't kick in on any existing Database Diagrams you might have.  These diagrams will continue to use the previous settings.
However, if I create a new Database Diagram, it will now use the font family & color which I selected... but it continues to completely ignore whatever font size I chose.
Perhaps this is a quirk as I'm using Windows 11 and an external monitor, and it's trying to be clever, and make the fonts over-large...?
